# Any way to group the result of a DISTINCT and get the COUNT of the rows grouped correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.buyer_id, u.username, a.cb_id
FROM winners AS w
INNER JOIN auctions AS a ON w.auction_id=a.auction_id AND a.cb_id > 0 AND a.category_id=1922
INNER JOIN users AS u ON w.buyer_id=u.user_id
```

So basically I am trying to find out how many *unique* entries each `w.buyer_id` has been involved in with regards to `a.cb_id`.

So to do that I ran the above query and I get a row by row result, which is good as it shows all the unique values; so I can see that user **A** has 14 rows (14 unique CB ID's they are involved in) and user **B** may have 5 rows.

So I want to make it so I can get a record set with an output of:

```
w.buyer_id,u.username,count
```

I tried the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.buyer_id, u.username, a.cb_id, COUNT(*) AS unique_spots
FROM winners AS w
INNER JOIN auctions AS a ON w.auction_id=a.auction_id AND a.cb_id > 0 AND a.category_id=1922
INNER JOIN users AS u ON w.buyer_id=u.user_id
GROUP BY w.buyer_id
LIMIT 5000;
```

...but it returns the `COUNT` as if I didn't even apply a `DISTINCT` to the record set.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The reason why you get the "wrong" result is simple: `DISTINCT` is processed **after** `GROUP BY`

Comment: @dnoeth Ahh, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just writing a query to do what you want directly?

```
SELECT w.buyer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.cb_id)
FROM winners w INNER JOIN
     auctions a
     ON w.auction_id = a.auction_id AND a.cb_id > 0 AND
        a.category_id = 1922 INNER JOIN
     users u ON w.buyer_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY w.buyer_id;
```

The join to `users` seems superfluous:

```
SELECT w.buyer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.cb_id)
FROM winners w INNER JOIN
     auctions a
     ON w.auction_id = a.auction_id AND a.cb_id > 0 AND
        a.category_id = 1922 
GROUP BY w.buyer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Some times I forget you can use `DISTINCT` within `COUNT` haha...... and I needed the username in the output, that's why it is there :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT w.buyer_id, u.username, a.cb_id, COUNT(*) AS unique_spots
FROM winners AS w
INNER JOIN auctions AS a ON w.auction_id=a.auction_id AND a.cb_id > 0 AND a.category_id=1922
INNER JOIN users AS u ON w.buyer_id=u.user_id
GROUP BY w.buyer_id, u.username, a.cb_id
LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: Naa, that gets the amount of spots for each unique `a.cb_id` rather than the amount of unique `a.cb_id`'s for each user.